# problem passing url in iphone app

Tags: iphone, nsurlrequest

Am passing a parameter to url and the parameter has special characters like space....
Also i tried replacing space with +

but the app is crashing......
Am not getting the reason

this is the URL : `https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=AIzaSyD0x-0JAexkHtyNv55u4_9zZNJGLn6h89s&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&country=US&q=***%@***&startIndex=%d&maxResults=%d&alt=atom`,

and the parameter is like **sony camera**

Am not getting the reason

Please help me with this issue.

Thaks in advance..

Comment: What does the crash log say? Can you attach the crash log?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass three parameters with types NSString,int,int . I think wrong type of your parameters causing the crash.
Try this method

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:YOUR_URL,parameter1, parameter2, parameter3];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL` will return `nil` if the URL passed to it is not valid. What  constitues a valid URL is [as follows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> NSURL objects understand URLs as
>   specified in RFCs 1808, 1738, and
>   2732.

In short, you'll probably need to escape your URL.